# Example applications of the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, laplace-transform

I am asking for applications of the Laplace Transform. I don't mean just ODE, because I know it's used there. I want some physics equations or maybe probability fields or any interesting exercises where the transform can be useful. I know it's being used in some simple electric circuits, but I want more. Do you know any examples?

Comment: http://sces.phys.utk.edu/~moreo/mm08/sarina.pdf, https://commons.emich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1540&context=honors, https://www.irjet.net/archives/V5/i5/IRJET-V5I5593.pdf, https://www.engr.siu.edu/staff/spezia/Web438A/Lecture%20Notes/lesson11et438a.pdf, https://www.amazon.com/Laplace-Transform-Applications-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986987, http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/NSJOM/Papers/45_1/NSJOM_45_1_031_044.pdf

Comment: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-20/issue-11/110502/Application-of-the-Laplace-transform-in-time-domain-optical-spectroscopy/10.1117/1.JBO.20.11.110502.full?SSO=1